# HTML margin-bottom for responsive navbar-fixed-bottom

Tags: html, css, navbar, footer, bootstrap-4

I have this `navbar-fixed-bottom` at the end of mi page.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="images/banner2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
```

I add a margin bottom for the HTML

```
html { margin-bottom: 100px }
```

.. to avoid the footer covers my content. That works fine for desktop resolution, but with smaller resolution, not. Thats because the `img` of the footer is responsive, so the height decrease, but not the `margin-bottom` of the HTML.

The question is how to make the `margin-bottom` of the html "responsive", depending on the navbar height.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it with

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {/
  html { margin-bottom: 50px }
}
```